# Responsive design not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
      <title></title>        

       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
   </head>
   <body>

      <section id="main">
            <div id="overlay"></div>
            <div id="conteudo" class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div id=""><span id="name"></span></div>
                    <div id=""><span></span></div>
                    <div id=""><span>&</span></div>
                    <div id=""><span>Web</span></div>
                </div>                  
            </div>
      </section>

      <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The path for the files .css and .js are right. Apparently, I did NOT forgot anything, but when I try to resize the window for a smaller size or use the "Adaptive Designe Size" of MozilaFireFox, the responsive does not work. Why ?

Comment: Did you try putting your scripts in the head?

Comment: @Shawn I don't think the *javaScript* files would be causing this issue. But I tried now and still the same problem =(

Comment: To test this I would put an alert javascript file in the same js folder and see if you see the alert OR use firebug or equiv. to see if those are indeed loading.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for help. I never used firebug, I'll try it now. It's the extension of FireFox, right ? No errors on FireBug.

Comment: Any chance you can create a fiddle of this? Also I notice you have id="" on all those internal divs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain that the paths to jquery and bootstrap.min.js are correct, the next thing I would check is your custom CSS in

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

Try commenting out or removing this line. It will probably change your layout, but more importantly, see if it helps the responsive behaviour.

If this does help, look for styles in your custom CSS which may be over riding or breaking the bootstrap CSS.

Good luck!